# Why my code fails with the second mouse button in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my code and desperately need your help.

I have a text (in UI) on my canvas and I want it to disappear with my first mouse click and reappear with the second but for some reason it doesn't reappear.

```
void Update() 
{
    Debug.Log ("start                      " + isHide);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1) && isHide == true) {
        Debug.Log ("after enter 1 and no change   " + isHide);
        text.gameObject.SetActive (false); 
        isHide = false;
        Debug.Log ("after enter 1 and change    " + isHide);
    } else {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1) && isHide == false) {
            Debug.Log ("after enter 2 and no change    " + isHide);
            text.gameObject.SetActive (true); 
            isHide = true;
            Debug.Log ("after enter 2 and change   " + isHide);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can't click on something that is not active. So you need to create an empty label op the same place, or make the .text value empty instead of disabling the object.

Answer on comment:

This is wat you want. I recreated your code very fast with the edit suggested by @La pieuvre:

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text text;
string oldTextValue = "";
bool isHide = true;
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log( "Start" );
    if( Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 1 ) )
    {
        Debug.Log( "Pressed Mouse button" );
        if( isHide == true )
        {
            Debug.Log( "Disabling Text" );
            oldTextValue = text.text;
            text.text = "";
            isHide = false;
        }
        else if ( isHide == false ) // Else it wil always just enable the button when u press your mouse.
        {
            Debug.Log( "Enabling Text" );
            text.text = oldTextValue;
            isHide = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make the .text value empty instead of disabling the object?

Answer (score 0):

Also, on top of what @livo said, your condition is not very clean. You better write :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)){ 
    if(isHiden){
      // your code
   }else{
      // your code
   }
}
```